# onmouseover Event in For Loop JavaScript Supplies Incorrect Arguments

Tags: javascript, function, dom

So, I have a for loop and an array. in each of the elements in that array are buttons, which I want to all have an `onmouseover` event.

*Note:* code is simplified to make my point.

```
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.onmouseover = function() {doSomething(i)};
}
```

where `doSomething` accepts one parameter, `i`.

When the cursor does hover over any of the butttons, the argument supplied to `doSomething` - `i`, is always the length of `array`, regardless of which button the cursor is hovering over. Why does this happen, and what can I do to ensure the correct arguments are supplied to the function?

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to the variable, not its value. I.e. you have successfully created a closure in which all functions utilize the same variable `i`, not a new variable with the value of `i`.

What you need to do is lock in that value and one way you can do this is to create a function generator and invoke it with that current value of `i`. E.g.

```
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.onmouseover = function(inner_i) { return function(){doSomething(inner_i)} }(i);
}
```

Comment: So I assume the `(i)` placed after the function definition assigns `i` to `inner_i` in the function declaration?